# Why do the error messages appear in this java code?

Tags: java

```
public class BadExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 3;
        int y = 7;
        computeSum();
    }
    public static void computeSum () {
        int sum = x + y;
        System.out.println("sum = " + sum);
    } 
}
```

Why do the error messages appear? I can read them but I don't know exactly what they mean?

Comment: Do you actually believe that `x` and `y` will be visible in `computeSum()`?

Comment: *Which* error messages?

Comment: Please add the relevant error messages. This is not enough information.

Answer (score 3):

you are not passing your x and y into the computeSum() method. to access it inside the method you need to pass it to your method.

```
public class BadExample {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            int x = 3;
            int y = 7;
            computeSum(x,y);
        }

         public static void computeSum (int x, int y) {
             int sum = x + y;
             System.out.println("sum = " + sum);
         }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly the explanation I needed.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the function doesn't know what x and y are.
A correct way to do this will be to pass x and y as parameters to the function like so :

```
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 3;
        int y = 7;
        computeSum(x ,y );
    }

     public static void computeSum (int x, int y) {
         int sum = x + y;
         System.out.println("sum =" + sum);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The method computeSum does not know what x and y are, so pass it in the arguments for the method.

```
public class BadExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 3;
        int y = 7;
        computeSum(x,y);
    }

     public static void computeSum (int x, int y) {
         int sum = x + y;
         System.out.println("sum = " + sum);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are assuming local variable defined in main function are accessible in other class member functions.

Variable defined inside a function are local to that function and are not accessible outside the scope of that function.

So correct implementation is to pass x and y as function parameters to computeSum(x,y) method.

```
     public class Sample {

     public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 3;
        int y = 7;
        computeSum(x ,y );
        }

     public static int computeSum (int x, int y) {
         int sum = x + y;
         System.out.println("sum =" + sum);
         return sum;
        }
     }
```

Also from design perspective computeSum method should take arguments as function params whose value it needs to compute and return the sum.